# Count specific rows

Tags: php

I am using bootstrap progress bar to display stats.

I want to know how many scored 10 points out of total no of rows.

```
$q="SELECT * FROM users";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$q);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($r);

Name   email          score time
Hello  abc@gmail.com  10   15
Hello  abc@gmail.com  58    10
Test   def@gmail.com  10   12 
Stack  xyz@gmail.com  90    20
Test   def@gmail.com  50    40
```

Comment: Do you only want to know how many scored 10? Or do you want it to be dynamic and have a percentage for every number scored?

Comment: Yes how many scored 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 out of total number of rows

Answer (score 0):

$q="SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM users WHERE score='10' ";

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple query to get it done :-

```
SELECT COUNT(name), score 
FROM users
GROUP BY score
```

This would get the total for each individual score (10,9,8).
If you want total only for value `10`. Use this instead.

```
SELECT COUNT(name), score 
FROM users
WHERE score=10
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the $total array and assign all the values less than 10 into an array then loop through that array to print out how many out of total for each less than 10.

```
    $total = [
        0 => [
            'name' => 'Hello',
            'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'score' => 10,
            'time' => 15
        ],
        1 => [
            'name' => 'Hello',
            'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'score' => 58,
            'time' => 10
        ],
        2 => [
            'name' => 'Test',
            'email' => 'def@gmail.com',
            'score' => 10,
            'time' => 12
        ],
        3 => [
            'name' => 'Stack',
            'email' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
            'score' => 90,
            'time' => 20
        ],
        4 => [
            'name' => 'Test',
            'email' => 'def@gmail.com',
            'score' => 50,
            'time' => 40
        ],
    ];

    $sizeOfArray = count($total);
    $arrayOfScoresLessThanTen = [];
    foreach($total as $value) {
        if($value['score'] <= 10) {
            if(isset($arrayOfScoresLessThanTen[$value['score']])) {
                $arrayOfScoresLessThanTen[$value['score']] ++;
            }
            else {
                $arrayOfScoresLessThanTen[$value['score']] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($arrayOfScoresLessThanTen as $key => $scoresLessThanTen) {
        echo 'Score: '. $key . ' number scored out of total: '. $scoresLessThanTen . '/'.$sizeOfArray;
    }
```

This has been tested and works with the array $total that I created to match the one you had in your table. I added my $total array so that you can test it for yourself.